# My FBX model with animation is 180 degree rotated in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, fbx

As you can see, unfortunately i could not fix my issue with my rotated model. I have imported my model in 3d max and my exported file was dramatically low quality vs original model.
I wonder if you give me some solution or any fbx editor to solve my model direction.
[image: 180 degree rotated fbx animation model]

Comment: You only showed the quality in a 3D modeling app and non in Unity. How are people supposed to know your issue?

Comment: Title about rotated model, content about model quality...

Comment: This picture is from unity,nor 3D modeling app nor any other app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your transform in 3dmax before export.

- Utilities panel > Utilities rollout > Reset XForm button
  or
- Enhanced menu: Edit menu > Transform > Reset Transform

Comment: As i mentioned before this model after import in 3Dmax and export again will be dramatically damaged and the quality will not stay unique.

Comment: I need some tools which can edit my current fbx file without loosing the quality